# List Manipulation: list_1 = [A, C, E] + list_2 = [B, D, F] → mergedList = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to combine 2 Lists of strings in Python:

```
list_1 = [A, C, E]
list_2 = [B, D, F]
```

And this would be the desired output

```
mergedList = [A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

I've tried to use the `itertools` module but I haven't had success.

Comment: Did you try combining e.g. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `zip`?

Comment: Do you want them strictly alternating, or do you want them sorted?

Comment: "ive tried to use the itertools module but i havent had success."— *What* did you try and what was the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and `itertools.chain`:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'C', 'E']
list_2 = ['B', 'D', 'F']

from itertools import chain

mergedList = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_1, list_2)))
```

Output: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`